# Networking issue in IBM x3650 after install Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp

I have a problem making TCP connections after a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation.
First of all, after booting the interface is always off. In my case the interface is manually configured and named `em2`.  I turn it on using `sudo ifup em2`. After that, I can ping  my gateway and public sites like `www.example.com`, and resolve DNS queries without issues.

However, when I try `sudo apt update` I have the same issue as [apt-get update very slow, stuck at "Waiting for headers"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers).

I'm also having issues with `ssh` in that it never connects from a remote location to the server and vice-versa.  When trying to `ssh` to remote servers, I get the following errors:

```
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Finally, I tested with:

```
nc example.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: example.com
```

and got no response.

Other things that I checked:

- There's no firewall configured.
- The mtu is configured in defaults (1500).

  ```
  $ sudo apparmor_status
  apparmor module is loaded.
  4 profiles are loaded.
  4 profiles are in enforce mode.
  /sbin/dhclient
  /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
  /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
  /usr/sbin/tcpdump
  0 profiles are in complain mode.
  0 processes have profiles defined.
  0 processes are in enforce mode.
  0 processes are in complain mode.
  0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
  ```

Comment: How about `sestatus` ?

Comment: I checked:

`$sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
4 profiles are loaded.
4 profiles are in enforce mode.
/sbin/dhclient
/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
/usr/sbin/tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.`

Comment: try to `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop` stop the service and see if it works without enforcement. if it works then configure apparmor accordingly

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: run this `/etc/init.d/apparmor stop ; /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown ; update-rc.d -f apparmor remove`

Answer (score 1):

Even with latest firmware and driver updates the server didn't make a TCP connection, but the problem was solved changing the motherboard. An IBM technician changed the motherboard and it started to work properly.

Really weird problem.